# Angular 2+ Creating a Toggle of 2 different cases

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a toggle in angular 4 calling a function when the click event is called.

```
<button (click)="toggle()">Toggle Button</button>
```

And then in the .ts file I want something like this:

```
toggle() {

    alert('toggle case 1') 

    else

    alert('toggle case 2');

}
```

Basically I want to have 2 different actions...how do I do this?

Comment: try to see this example this may help you out https://plnkr.co/edit/oLkktUH5zZePlcAsWumq?p=info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to toggle a simple boolean you can do the following:

```
<button (click)="toggle()">Toggle Button</button>
```

---

```
class MyComponent {
  isToggled: boolean;

  toggle() {
    this.isToggled = !this.isToggled;
  }
}
```

Then you can use `isToggled` in your view, if needed.

For something more complicated you can expand your `toggle()` method like so:

```
toggle() {
  this.isToggled = !this.isToggled;

  if (this.isToggled) {
    // do something, we've just been toggled on
  } else {
    // do something else, we've just been toggled off
  }
}
```

Comment: I need an if else in there so I can add an action to each case

Comment: I have updated my answer, but the method was just an example for tracking the toggled state - do whatever you want inside the toggle method.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a Boolean in your component and act by its value.

```
<button (click)="toggle()">Toggle Button</button>

toggleFlag:boolean=false;

toggle() {
    this.toggleFlag=!this.toggleFlag;
    if(this.toggleFlag)
       alert('toggle case 1')     
    else
       alert('toggle case 2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Template

```
<button (click)="toggle()">Toggle Button</button>
```

.ts file

```
button_clicked = false;

toggle() {
    this.button_clicked = !this.button_clicked;
    if(this.button_clicked) 
    { 
        // call function 1 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        // call function 2
    }
}
```